# Systemd fails bringing up OpenVPN service because it triggers raising interface that already exists

Tags: openvpn, systemd

I have an openvpn server that's supposed to be started by systemd. Just recently the service failed to come up, because for some reason it triggers raising network interfaces but ifup fails to bring up a network interface because it already exists.

The server has two interfaces, one connected to the internet (openvpn is supposed to listen on that) and one to the LAN. The Openvpn supposed to tunnel to the LAN interface. The LAN interface is the one that fails: enp97s0f0

```
Feb 20 11:03:35 server ifup[5035]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 20 11:03:35 server ifup[5035]: ifup: failed to bring up enp97s0f0
Feb 20 11:03:35 server systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 20 11:03:35 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Feb 20 11:03:35 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for OpenVPN connection to inline.
-- Subject: Unit openvpn@inline.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit openvpn@inline.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
```

Why is openvpn.service trying to raise the internal network interface when it already exists?

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service for %I 
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Documentation=man:openvpn(8)
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
RuntimeDirectory=openvpn-server
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0710
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn/server
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --status %t/openvpn-server/status-%i.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --config %i.conf
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE
LimitNPROC=10
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tun rw

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can I prevent it to try bringing up the interface (like assuming the interface is always up).

Comment: Is the problem occured only at boot or also after an "service openvpn stop;service openvpn start" ?

Comment: It appears after boot and after trying to bring it up manually using service openvpn start/systemctl start openvpn

Comment: How are you bringing up the wired network interface?

Comment: It's done via netctl I suppose. It's running by default on boot.